# How to create background task inside a cog in discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, schedule, background-task

I am trying to create a task inside a cog. This is code I currently have,

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import schedule
from discord.ext import commands


class BotTasks(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.mytask())
        

    def job():
        print("task")
        
    schedule.every().day.at("19:44").do(job)

    async def mytask():
        
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            await asyncio.sleep(1)



def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(BotTasks(bot))
```

I feel the code is correct but the problem is with `self.bg_task = self.loop.create_task(self.mytask())`, idk what else to put in place of that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `discord.ext.tasks`

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

class BackgroundTasks(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
 
    @tasks.loop(seconds=5) # <- will do this every 5 seconds
    async def my_background_task(self, *args):
        # do something
```

To start it

```py
my_background_task.start(some_arguments) # <- you can put this in a command or in the on_ready event
```

Here are a few more useful functions

```py
loop.stop()
loop.cancel()
loop.restart()
```

Reference:

- [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.Loop)